# React conditional style not rendering properly

Tags: reactjs, redux

Okay, so I'm having a very interesting issue with conditionally rendering a style with a `className`, it works for one table but not the other.

I'm using react version 15.6.2

I map over the data and return the first table row or the second based on if it's a buy or not.

```
if (isBuy) {
      return (
        <tr key={i} className={( newOrder ? 'updatedOrderTr' : '' )} onClick={() => this.props.populateOrderForm(amount, price, isBuy)}>
          <td>{order[1].user_depth}</td>
          <td>{numberWithDelimiter((price * amount).toFixed(prec))}</td>
          <td>{amount}</td>
          <td>{price.toFixed(prec)}</td>
        </tr>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <tr key={i} className={( newOrder ? 'updatedOrderTr' : '' )} onClick={() => this.props.populateOrderForm(amount, price, isBuy)}>
          <td>{price.toFixed(prec)}</td>
          <td>{amount}</td>
          <td>{numberWithDelimiter((price * amount).toFixed(prec))}</td>
          <td>{order[1].user_depth}</td>
        </tr>
      );
    }
```

I render two instances of this component which passes down an array of arrays structured like this

```
[ [1, {volume: 1, price: 3}], [2, {volume: 4, price: 2}] ]
```

The only difference is one table is the sell orders table and one is a buy orders table where the table cells get reversed.

The buy orders rows get rendered fine and the style shows up properly when  it is supposed to (when newOrder is true).

The sell orders table rows only work randomly. Here's a video.

https://giphy.com/gifs/3o7aCPUNIy9oA46Y8g/fullscreen

Notice how I have to spam it to get the right side to actually flash. When in reality the code is the exact same , only the td's are reversed...

I'm very confused and have spent many hours playing around with it.

I have tried making the class that gets applied styles just simply a solid background instead of an animation.

This is what I check the condition of. Which checks the orders array current index vs the previous state of that array.

```
const newOrder = JSON.stringify(this.props.data[i]) !== JSON.stringify(this.state.previousTable[i]);
```

Would really appreciate any helping hands!

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for errors? Also can you include your code for your populateOrderForm method?

Comment: No console errors. The populateOrderForm method is irrelevant to my issue. It's a complete different feature. The issue is with rendering the table rows on the right side. For whatever reason they only work periodically... Which blows my mind because the code is literally the same except the cells are swapped

Comment: The reason I asked to see populateOrderForm is because your issue could be due to you mutating state and getting weird side-effects. Not sure if your app is sharing data between the two lists of data? if they are and your code is mutating the data you could get odd effects.

Comment: Thanks Ben. I've tried removing the populateOrderForm from the element with no change. Anything else you think would be worth while sharing to you? EDIT: I passed the same data from the left table to the right as props and it flashes... But both arrays have the structure. I don't understand what is differen't.

Comment: The two other things Id try is comment out the table which works. If the other table then works the issue could be down to some shared data or an odd id/key clash (which I wouldnt have thought is the problem tbh). Have you tried ensuring that the keys of the tr's in the two tables are totally different?

Comment: I have commented out the table that works. And the right table (sell orders) still does not work. This is driving me nuts!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157154/discussion-between-hayden-carlson-and-ben-smith).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by checking nextProps compared to currentProps and if there was a change in them I then set the state causing a re render.

The reason why the right table (sell orders) didn't update is because there was buy data and sell data coming down the socket. The sell orders going first almost every time (that's why it would work periodically).

Because I was not checking if the props changed, the state was getting set multiple times and I was unable to see the style.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
  if (this.props.data !== props.data) {
    this.setState({previousTable: this.props.data});
  }
}
```